# how to sent request to discord bot API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

How do I properly send a discord API request, and where do I get a valid token to do that because my discord bot token did not work there?

```js
async function APIrequest(){
    
    const lib = require('lib')({token: 'which API key?'});
    
    let result = await lib.discord.channels['@0.3.2'].retrieve({
      channel_id: channelid
    });
    
    console.log("result")
    console.log(result)
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I assume you'll find what you are looking for here:
https://discord.com/developers/docs/getting-started#overview

I've included some of the info below. Also pay attention to rate limiting as api keys can be revoked if you step outside the guidelines.

Post could have been improved with more details of exactly what you want. Have you checked the docs and been unable to find answers?

[image]